# Why can't we access bits that we pad in structures?

Tags: c, linux, struct, padding

My question is we do padding to align structures.

```
typedef struct structb_tag
{
   char c;
   int  i;
} structb_t;
```

Here we use 8 bytes. Why can't we use the 3 bytes that lot?

Comment: You chose not to stick any fields there. If you wanted to use those bytes, you should have defined your struct differently.

Comment: How would you refer to them?  They have no name — and different compilers could use different amounts of padding.

Comment: You can, using pointers.

Comment: @LP: But you shouldn't.

Comment: @alk Yes, for sure. ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Why cant we use the 3 bytes

You could.

To do so measure the size your implementation allocates for a `struct` and then make it a union adding a char-array of exactly the size measured and there you go.

Assuming this

```
typedef struct structb_tag
{
   char c;
   int i;
} structb_t;
```

is created using eight bytes, that is `sizeof (structb_t)` evaluates to `8`, change it to the following

```
typedef union unionb_tag
{
  char bytes[8];
  struct
  {
    char c;
    int i;
  } structb;
}
```

More reliable, in terms of portability and also robustness, would be this:

```
typedef union unionb_tag
{
  struct structb_tag
  {
    char c;
    int i;
  } structb;
  char bytes[sizeof (struct structb_tag)];
}
```

Comment: you can define a struct tag (`structb_tag`), move `bytes` array declaration after struct def and declare it as `char bytes[sizeof(struct structb_tag)];`

Comment: @LPs: I had just started to propose exactly this ...:)

Comment: Won't the padding values become indeterminate whenever you do anything with the struct part of the union?

Comment: @user2357112: Correct, you do not want to read them, before having written to them .. - as usual.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GCC and space is the most important thing for you instead of speed (which padding provides) you could just request the compiler to not do the padding, `struct __attribute__((__packed__)) mystruct`, padding is the way for compiler to align structures in the natural for faster access.

Answer (score 0):

You can always take the pointer to the structure convert it to a byte pointer and access any byte of that structure.

This is dangerous way, though.

Answer (score 0):

The padding are implementation dependent, which are not defined by the standard, you cannot not use them as there is no way to reference the padding bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

```
typedef struct structb_tag
{
   char        c;
   char        pad[3];
   int         i;
} structb_t;

structb_t test;
test.pad[0] = 'a';
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, we can use that three bytes.

The reason why we need 3 bytes padding is for memory usage optimization, so the compiler will help us add an gap between c and i. So when you use

```
typedef struct structb_tag
{
   char        c;
   int         i;
} structb_t;
```

It actually

```
typedef struct structb_tag
{
   char        c;
   char[3]     unseen_members;
   int         i;
} structb_t;
```

Accessing these unseen members will not cause any segmentation fault. In the point of view of OS, there's no difference between accessing members declared by programmers explicitly and declared by compiler implicitly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct Test {
    char c;
    int i;
} MyTest;

int main() {
    MyTest my_test;
    memset(&my_test, 0, sizeof(my_test)); 

    my_test.c = 1;
    int* int_ptr = (int *)&my_test.c; 

    printf("Size of my_test is %lu\n", sizeof(my_test));
    printf("Value of my_test.c(char) is %d\n", my_test.c);
    printf("Value of my_test.c(int) is %d\n", *int_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives:

```
Size of my_test is 8
Value of my_test.c(char) is 1
Value of my_test.c(int) is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can access any byte in the structure using a pointer to that structure and typecasting that pointer to (char *) if we accordingly increment that pointer then we can access any byte but this not good programming skill. Structures are padded with some extra bytes so that an execution of the program can become faster.